# Android 2.3X kills Apps into the Background

Tags: java, android

I always used Android 2.2 for my Apps. But currently I upgraded to Android 2.3.X Gingerbread. So if I start my App and go back to the android "desktop", the app is kill by 3-4 Minutes.

I think it will be killed after some minutes inactivity, but I need to run it in background to read some mobile status.

How can I set my App as a "Background" App, so that Android will not longer kill it?

Thanks for Help...

Regards, Rookee

Answer (score 1):

To run an application in the background it must be of type "Service". You have to register a service and it will run in your device forever. For more info, [Android Services](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: It will not "run forever". Even services will be shut down after a while, though longer than if the application did not use a service. A well-designed Android application will not try to have something running continuously **unless it is continuously delivering value to the user** (e.g., playing back music), in which case it can use a `Service` and `startForeground()` to minimize the odds that it will be shut down unexpectedly.